# Is there a technical term for a cube where each edge is 2 units? If so what is the term?

Tags: geometry, terminology

I frequently work with code where I sample from a 3D cube bounded by -1,-1,-1 to 1,1,1 centred at 0,0,0.

It would be handy to know if it has a technical name, so my code can be consistent with mathematical convention.

Which leads to my question, is there a technical term for a cube where each edge is 2 units? If so what is the term?

Comment: As a side note, the reason I require a cube of this size is that it is paired with a unit sphere co-located at 0,0,0.

Comment: A "cube of side $2$"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [unit ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_sphere#Unit_balls_in_normed_vector_spaces) for the [maximum metric (or norm)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry), a special case of an [$\ell_p$ norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#p-norm) for $p=\infty$.

Comment: Thanks.  Just read the wikipedia link.  So something like "manhattan unit ball" would be appropriate?

Comment: @JohnForbes: I don't know of a shorter way to express it than "unit ball in/for/under the maximum norm"; "maximum unit ball" wouldn't work. By the way, there are closed and open balls (according to whether you do or don't include the boundary, respectively).

Comment: @joriki +1 though I'd call this a "*most obfuscated math term*" rather than `technical term` ;-)

Comment: @JohnForbes: Sorry about the original mistake (and the resulting confusion in the comments).